# Meaning of adjective + にする

Tags: grammar, meaning, particle-に, adjectives

When you say

> 部屋をきれいにします

You mean "Clean the room" (make it so that the room becomes clean).

On the other hand, when you say

> 静かにする

You mean "Be quiet".

If these meanings are right, would the sentences

> すべてが静かにする
>
> すべてを静かにする

mean, respectively, "Everything is quiet" and "Make everything quiet" ?

Lastly, what would be the difference in meaning between the following:

> すべてが静かにする
>
> すべてが静かにある

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 部屋をきれいにします
>   "Clean the room" (make it so that the room becomes clean).
>
> 静かにする
>   "Be quiet".

The する in きれいにする means "to make", and the する in 静かにする means "to behave".

> すべてが静かにする

する as "to behave~~" is (usually) used for animate things. So you can say 全員が静かにする, みんなが静かにする "Everyone stays quiet", すべての生徒が静かにする "All the students stay quiet" etc., but すべてが静かにする sounds a bit unnatural. For "Everything is quiet", you'd say すべてが静かである*, すべてが静かだ, etc.

> すべてを静かにする

means "make everything quiet". ～を静かに**させる** sounds more natural to me but it'd probably depend on the context.

> すべてが静かにある

静かにある is grammatically incorrect. You'd say 静かである* or 静かだ.

So, for example for "All the students are quiet," you could say:

> すべての生徒が静かにしている。
>   すべての生徒が静かである / 静かだ。

The former is like "All the students are being/staying quiet now", and the latter "All the students are quiet (now, or always)".

<sub>*である sounds more literary/formal than だ.</sub>

Comment: I focused so much on にする that completely overlooked 静かにある is ungrammatical... Also, knowing that する can mean "to behave" made more sense. The main point, which was the difference between the transitive する and the intransitive one, you solved, so thank you @chocolate.

Answer (score -2):

Not native, not fluent.

Just a guess:

> すべてが静かにある

I think that's just describing the current state of affairs. "Everything is quiet".

It's probably similar to ってある form, as in:

> 〇〇書いてある

Something something is written