# Verb te form + くれて

Tags: grammar, て-form

So I was helping this girl with her English sentences and she sent me this:

正しくしてくれてありがとう

As the context goes I guess it means "thanks for correcting me"

There's a lot of things confusing me on this sentence, first:

1. Why's she using the adverb 正しく instead of the verb 正す？ does it comes from something like 正しいする?
2. Now we have してくれて which is te form of する+くれて, what does it mean? Could this sentence be said in a different way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have been using 助けてくれてありがとうwhich I am assuming means Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Why's she using the adverb 正しく instead of the verb 正す？ does it comes from something like 正しいする?

I think it's not just a simple use of adverb. I.e. you would not in this case parse 正しく+する to mean "correctly do" as you would parse 速く+歩く to mean "quickly walk".

- Consider [静かにする](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/39775/meaning-of-adjective-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B). Although the syntax is adverb+verb, 静かに+する, but it may take on the meaning of "be(make) quiet" in addition to "quietly do".
- So in your case of 正しくして it means "to make correct". 正しく is conjugated from 正しい to be an adverb.

> 2. Now we have してくれて which is te form of する+くれて, what does it mean? Could this sentence be said in a different way?

- [くれる(see diagram in the linked answer)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/404/542) is an auxiliary that means "for me". It indicates the beneficiary of the action and its formation rules is that it comes after the て form. So 正しくしてくれる means "make correct for me".

  - also see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/308/542) for a primer on verbs for giving and receiving. (Maybe you should look for a good textbook, all textbooks should deal with giving and receiving verbs)
- くれる is further inflected to its て form くれて in order to append ありがとう after it. ～てありがとう is a structure that means "thank you for ～".

Combined, 正しくしてくれてありがとう can be parsed as "thank you for making it correct for me" = "thanks for correcting me"

Comment: The diagram in the link is inaccurate in the point that it can't explain well about cases where you use やる when the 3rd person gives to the 2nd person and くれる when the 2nd person gives to the 3rd person.

Comment: @user4092 Is it inaccurate or incomplete?

Comment: You can say it's incomplete if it said there's a case that contradicts to the diagram (when "you" belongs to an out-group and "he" belongs to an in-group; this binary method still can't treat cases in which both the giver and the receiver belong to the same category, though).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I've bee a bit busy these days. Oh, it was quite simple actually, I pretty much understood everything! Hmm Do you know any good text books I should get? Right now my learning method is pretty much an app called "obekyou" (android), chatting on hello talk and this forum. Do you think that using a textbook or something else could help me to get better results? Thanks man!